# How to download files without via temporary folder in WinSCP?

Tags: winscp

I install the WinSCP (not using a portable version). I have already disabled this option in the WinSCP. But the files are still downloaded to temporary folders first before cut & paste to the destination folder. How can I directly download files to where I want?

[image]

[image]

---

Here is an update that "Shell extension is installed and loaded". But still the same problem. The file being downloaded is 0 kB all the time after refreshing the Windows Explorer, while it is already many MB downloaded.
[image]

---

Here is the log file.

```
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Copying 1 files/directories to local directory "D:\Users\xxxxxxx\Downloads\" - in parallel, with 1 total files - total size: 143,512,657,063
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1]   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: N (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: *.*
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1]   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1]   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] File: '/xxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.tar.bz2' [2022-06-10T21:31:41.000Z] [143512657063]
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Copying "/xxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.tar.bz2" to local directory started.
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Opening remote file.
> 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 85, Number: 590083
< 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 589828
. 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Discarding reserved response
< 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 590083
> 2022-07-27 14:56:58.486 [Background 1] Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 590344
< 2022-07-27 14:56:58.502 [Background 1] Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 590344
> 2022-07-27 14:56:58.502 [Background 1] Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 25, Number: 590597
. 2022-07-27 14:57:15.616 [Background 1] 1683 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2022-07-27 14:57:15.616 [Background 1] Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 806148
```

Comment: Do you really want to do that? In case one file partially fails to transfer and you miss the error message, you might end up with a corrupted file.

Comment: I need to download many hundreds of GB files to my mobile HDD, as my local PC does not have enough space.

Comment: The log says that the file is downloaded to `D:\Users\xxxxxxx\Downloads`. Is this the *"temporary folder" * that you are referring to? Or is it the final folder?

Comment: It is the final destination folder

Comment: So then WinSCP is downloading files directly to the destination folder. What makes you think it is first downloading them to some temporary folder? Show us some evidence of that.

Answer (score 0):

The *"Shell extension is installed, but is not loaded"* is the key.

If it is a new installation, try restarting your computer. If not, try reinstalling WinSCP first.

Comment: thank you. The "shell extension" is loaded now, but still the same problem.

Comment: *"The file being downloaded is 0 kB all the time after refreshing the Windows Explorer, while it is already many MB downloaded"* – What does that prove? What does WinSCP session log file say about the download? Where is WinSCP downloading files too?

Comment: In general log file would be useful, seeing that others react to your "transfer to temporary file" screenshot, which I believe your problem/question is NOT about. But I might be wrong. The log file and the progress dialog screenshots might tell us more.

Comment: How to get the log file?

Comment: There's *Logging* page on the Preferences dialog. Just check your screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary file might be required for supporting resume,
so if the transfer is interrupted the user doesn't end up with
a truncated file.

Try to add to the WinSCP call the parameter `-resumesupport=off`
to transfer without resume.

Comment: -resumesupport=off should be the same thing as the dialog the OP shows in the first picture.  I am looking at the source right now.

Comment: Can you tell me how to "add to the WinSCP call the parameter -resumesupport=off" ?

Comment: Use `WinSCP -resumesupport=off`.

Comment: Sorry, how to do this ```WinSCP -resumesupport=off ``` ?

Comment: Yes, invoke it with the parameter. Does it help?

Comment: Sorry, how to "invoke it with the parameter"?

Comment: Run the command like this : `WinSCP -resumesupport=off`.